# Passing Pandas dataframe columns as function arguments

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe

I have a dataframe called df. I need to pass columns as arguments to a function.

Outside the function, this code works :

`df.colname.fillna(method='ffill')`

If I use the following code (ie the same line inside the function and pass df.colname as the argument (colname = df.colname) it does not work. The line is ignored:

```
   def Funct (colname):
    
    colname.fillna(method='ffill')
```

This works (colname = df.colname):

```
def Funct (colname):
    colname [1:] = colname[1:].fillna(method='ffill')
```

What's happening?

Does the function change the dataframe object to an array? does this make the code inefficient and is there a better way of doing this?

(Note: This is part of a larger function which I am paraphrasing here for simplicity)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fillna()` by default does not update the dataframe in place, instead expecting you to assign it back, such as

```
def Funct(colname):
    return colname.fillna(method='ffill')

df = Funct(df)
```

It's worth mentioning that `fillna()` does have an argument `inplace=` which you could set to `True` if you need to update in place.